# Continuous and Differentiable in relation to Rolle's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have just learned about Rolle's theorem but need some clarification on the differentiable part.

Part of the theorem states that let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$.

The part I am confused on is stating what interval $x$ is in when referring to differentiability.

For example, given $f(x) = (x-a)^2(x-b)^4$ on $[a,b]$. We know that it is continuous since it is a polynomial. Then $f'(x)= 2(x-a)(x-b)^4+4(x-a)^2(x-b)^3$ exists

This is the part I am unsure of due to seeing it both ways:

for all $x \in [a,b]$  **or**

for all x $\in$ (a,b).

If someone could explain which one is right, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It has to be continuous on the closed interval and differentiable on the open interval. The reason we restrict differentiability to the open interval is because the limit involved in taking the derivative has to exist for both the right and left hand limits.

Comment: If you are differentiable on all of $[a,b]$ (as is the case in your polynomial example) then Rolle's theorem applies. But the minimal hypothesis for that theorem to work are weaker: you don't need to be differentiable at the end points. Being differentiable on $(a,b)$ is enough. Of course it's even better if the function is differntiable at the end points $a$ and $b$, but it's not necessary when applying this theorem. Think for instance about the function $\sqrt{x}$ on $[0,1]$: it is continuous on $[0,1]$ but only differentiable on $(0,1]$.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat A better example is $|\sin{x}|$ since it is defined everywhere. It is continuous on $[0, \pi]$ but not differentiable there. Rolle's theorem applies because it is differentiable on the open interval.

Comment: @JohnDouma $|\sin(x)|$ isn't all that good an example. Yes, it is defined everywhere (but in Rolle this is not the issue), more importantly, when restricted to $[0,\pi]$ it *is* differentiable at the end points.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Not without defining right and left hand derivatives. If we are willing to do that then we don't need to restrict differentiability to the open interval.

Comment: The reason for excluding differentiability at endpoints in Rolle's theorem isn't that one doesn't want to define left or right derivatives which in any case have the same definition as the derivative in an interior point. It's that differentiability at those points genuinely isn't required.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat It's equivalent. If you define left and right hand derivatives then you get around the fact that a function is not differentiable, in general, at that point. The two characterizations of the theorem are the same but the open interval requirement avoids the extra work.

Answer (score 2):

$f$ differentiable on $(a,b)$ and continuous on $[a,b]$ is sufficient.
If $f$ was differentiable on $[a,b]$ then the above mentioned condition will be satisfied because differentiable functions are continuous and if $f$ is differentiable in the closed interval then of course it will be differentiable in the open interval .
Note that there do exist functions satisfying the conditions which are not differentiable on the closed interval but differentiable on the open interval .

Comment: +1. For example $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and $f(x)=\sqrt {x(1-x)}$.

Comment: The key in the proof is that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and if $f(a)=f(b)$ then there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f(c)=\max \{f(x):x\in [a,b]\}$ OR there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f(c)=\min \{f(x):x\in [a,b]\}$.